# Spring batch - using in-memory database for huge file processing

Tags: java, spring-batch, cpu-usage

I am using Spring batch to process huge data (150 GB) to produce 60 GB output file. I am using Vertical Scaling approach and with 15 threads (Step partitioning approach).

The Job execution details are stored in the in-memory database. The CPU Utilization is more because its running on single machine and the file size is huge. But the Server is having a good configuration like 32 core processor and i am using 10 GB memory for this process.

My question is, if i move this to separate database will it reduce some CPU Utilization? Also, Using In-Memory database for Production is a bad choice /decision?

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are talking about moving from in-memory db to a separate db, you are just talking about the batch runtime tables (job_instance, job_execution, step_execution, ...), right?

If so, I wouldn't expect that the CPU usage will drop a lot. Depending on your chunksize, a lot more CPU usage will be needed for your data processing, than for your updating the batch runtime tables.

If using an in-memory db for production is a good decision or not, depends on your needs. Two points to consider:

- You lose any-information which was written into the batch-runtime tables. This could be helpful for debug sessions or simply to have a kind of history. But you can "persist" such information also in logfiles.
- You will not be able to implement a restartable job. This could be an issue, if your job takes hours to complete. But for job, that only reads from a file, writes to a file, and is completed within a couple of minutes, this is not really a problem.